# Постановка кавычек в слове "ежик"

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, будьте добры, следует ли брать в кавычки слово "ежик" в значении "прическа"?

Answer (score 2):

Кавычки не нужны — значение слова зафиксировано словарями.

[ЁЖИК](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?game=x&all=x&word=%E5%E6%E8%EA), *-а; **м.***
**3.** Мужская короткая стрижка, при которой волосы стоят торчком. // Коротко стриженные, стоящие торчком волосы; бобрик. *Короткий ёжик. Седой ёжик. Ёжик густых жёстких волос.*
**<Ёжиком. I. *в зн. нареч.*** Так, что остаются стоячие волосы (о стрижке). *Стриженная ёжиком голова.* **II. *в зн. прил.*** Находящийся в стоячем положении (о волосах). *Волосы ёжиком.* **Под ёжик, *в зн. нареч.*** Оставляя стоячие волосы; бобриком. *Стричься под ёжик.*

*Двое. За рулём – помоложе: темноглазый, носатый, стриженый плотным **ёжиком*** (В. Зенкин); *Спутанные волосы повыбивались клоками из когда-то аккуратно заплетенной косы, надо лбом торчал стриженный **ежик*** (Э. Даржан); *Может, только пристальней стал взгляд, да гуще отливал ковылем бурый **ежик** волос* (А. Солин); *Шитый у портного костюм, серебряный **ежик** волос, манера слушать так, как обычно слушают докладчика* (С. Кулаков).